# How to remove the border line for each bar in bar chart using core plot?

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I am getting a line around each bars in bar chart. How to remove it. I made borderWidth to zero even I am getting line around each bars in bar chart.

Answer (score 7):

Turn off the borders around bar graph lines by setting the `lineStyle` property to nil.

Before setting `linestyle=nil`:

[image: Before linestyle equals nil]

After setting `linestyle=nil`:

[image: After linestyle equals nil]

For example:

```
CPTBarPlot *myBarGraph = [[CPTBarPlot alloc] init];
myBarGraph.lineStyle = nil;
```

I found this setting in the CorePlot CPTBarPlot class documentation, [here](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/interface_c_p_t_bar_plot.html#ada02529fb454bde898da35acaba1ed83).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this effect is to set the outline colour to clear by creating a `CPTMutableLineStyle` object, setting its `lineColor` to `clearColor`, and assigning the CPTMutableLineStyle object to your plot.

For example:

```
CPTMutableLineStyle *myBorderLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
myBorderLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor clearColor];
myPlot.lineStyle = myBorderLineStyle;
```